# Convert CWP file (Cakewalk Studio) to MIDI/WAV/MP3

Tags: file-format

I don't own Cakewalk studio any more but I have a bunch of old .CWP files I'd like to convert to MIDI/WAV/MP3. How is this possible without purchasing Cakewalk

Comment: Well, I did check out Google. I was hoping a really super user with super special knowledge might really super help me out! I was unaware that software recommendations are off topic - but I cannot think of a more appropriate SE site, so what should I do with this?

Comment: Actually, there is a new [software recommendations site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (but cross posting isn't allowed). I updated your question to remove the free tool, and just ask 'how' and it puts it on topic  :)

Comment: Any way, does Cakewalk not offer a trial version? If so, use the trial version, convert your files and job done?

Comment: ^ This guy's got the answer. I installed their new product, SONAR X3, it didn't load the projects quite correctly, but I was able to fix them and basically retrieve the data. Stick that in an answer Dave so I can give you your +15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to download a trial version of the software, convert all your files and job done!

As per your comments, in this case you used their new product and although it didn't read the old format perfectly, they only required minor tweaks to fix.

Comment: Actually, the trial doesn't convert the files. You have to purchase the full version.